# AsyncFacebookRunner implementation for login and wallpost

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

i'm trying to create a Facebook utility class and so far it worked pretty good but when i test it on APIs greater than ICS i get this error.

> 09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:71)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:193)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:751)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.infobest.praiser.share.ShareFacebook.postWall(ShareFacebook.java:99)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.infobest.praiser.share.ShareFacebook.send(ShareFacebook.java:47)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.infobest.praiser.activity.PraiseActivity$7.onClick(PraiseActivity.java:472)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:924)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   09-27 07:43:50.706: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

how can i implement AsyncFacebookRunner if my class looks like this

{

```
public String msg;
public Context ctx;
public Facebook fb;
public SharedPreferences sp;

public ShareFacebook(String msg, Context ctx, Facebook fb, SharedPreferences sp)
{
    this.msg = msg;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.fb = fb;
    this.sp = sp;

}

public void send()
{
    if (fb.isSessionValid())
    {
        postWall();
    }
    else
    {

        fb.authorize((Activity) ctx, new String[] {"email", "publish_checkins",
            "publish_stream"}, new DialogListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();   

            } 

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,R.string.facebookError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values)
            {
                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
                postWall();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {

            }
        });
    }

}

private void postWall()
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message",  msg );
    params.putString("link",ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.rateLink));
    params.putString("picture",
        ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher).toString());
    try
    {
        fb.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
        Toast.makeText(ctx,R.string.facebookSuccess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call Facebook.request() from the UI thread.

It only happens on ICS and above because ICS checks to ensure that you don't try and do network comms on the UI thread.

From the method comments in the facebook api:

> Note that this method blocks waiting for a network response, so do not call it in a UI thread.

Creating a thread and running fb.request from the thread should resolve the error.